# Redis equivalent of ActiveRecord::Base.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)?

Tags: ruby, redis

What's the redis equivalent of `ActiveRecord::Base.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)`? I want to see what redis is up to.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I usually want to set some additional attributes (such as the redis DB name). You can pass on arguments in the initialize method like this

```
$redis = Redis.new(db: Rails.config.redis.db, logger: Rails.logger)
```

Answer (score 9):

> $redis.client.logger = Rails.logger

It's better!

Answer (score 1):

Never mind. It's easy:

```
$redis = Redis.new(:host => 'localhost', :port => 6379)
$redis.client.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)
```

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a gem call RedisLogger:

https://github.com/hellolucky/redis_logger